# Automapper configuration for object

Tags: automapper-3

I have these classes

```
    public class NamedEntityViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class NamedEntityListViewModel
    {
        public List<NamedEntityViewModel> List { get; set; }
    }
    public class Album : INamedEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AlbumNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a `List<Album>` and I want to map that to `NamedEntityListViewModel` with `NamedEntityViewModel.Name` mapping to Album.Name.  How do I set this up in Automapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

First create you mapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Album, NamedEntityViewModel>();
```

For the mapping do this:

```
// yourAlbumList is a List<Album>
var albumListVm = new NamedEntityListViewModel();
albumListVm.List = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<NamedEntityViewModel>>(yourAlbumList);
```

This should do the job